# How to apply DRY principle for repeated blade patterns in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the sample `blade` pattern below repeated accross 2 views. I wonder how can I apply DRY principle for that. It is inside a `@foreach` loop, so it is produced 20 times for each view. I don't want to use `@include`, because I think all unnecessary variables passed to the include file on each call (repeated for 20 times also).

Because of patterns like the one below, I have upto 1000 lines of `blade` files. Is it normal, or is there something I can do for that.

Thanks.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    ...
    <div class="post-header">
        {{ mb_convert_case(str_replace('i', 'İ', $post->user->first_name), MB_CASE_TITLE) }} has posted, 

        @if($nhits)
            @if(isset($nhits[$post->id]))
                it has {{ $nhits[$post->id] }} hits,
            @endif
        @endif

        @if($post->likings->count())
            @if($post->likings->count())
                {{ $post->likings->count() }} persons liked it, 
            @else
                nobody liked it,
            @endif
        @endif

        @if($post->comments->count())
            {{ $post->comments->count() }} comments received.
        @else
            no comments yet.
        @endif
    <div>
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: _"I don't want to use @include"_ - Well, then you've basically removed the best way of solving it since this is basically what partials are for (which is loaded with `@include`).

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson But there are keywords like component, slot etc. Why downvote?

Comment: The DV wasn't me. All you mention is still loaded with `@include`. The differences are more about what they contain. If you want to reuse some markup, you need to put it in it's own file and then include it. Since you should use some template caching, that should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you looked into components and slots?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a **view composer** can help you organise that logic into a single location.  The example use cases often cited are the sidebar in a blog or a uses profile information in the header.

1. Register the view composers within a service provider
2. Define the composer class

You can also attach a view composer to multiple views at once by passing an array of views as the first argument to the composer method.

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.

From the Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

If the data will be different in each view, you can use **Components and Slots**.

From Laravel docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots

Create a reusable component to reuse throughout your application

```
<!-- /resources/views/alert.blade.php -->

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

Construct the component in the blade view

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<div class="alert-title">{{ $title }}</div>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

Inject the data

```
@component('alert')
    @slot('title')
        Forbidden
    @endslot

    You are not allowed to access this resource!
@endcomponent
```

Pass additional data in an array of data as the second argument to the @component directive. All of the data will be made available to the component template as variables.

```
@component('alert', ['foo' => 'bar'])
    ...
@endcomponent
```